# what is the difference betweeen these two OnlineUsers Methods in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

plz see my global.asax :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using DataLayer;
using NiceFileExplorer.Classes;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace NiceFileExplorer
{

    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application["OnlineUsers"] = 0;
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Lock();

            OnlineUsers.InsertRow(
                Session.SessionID,
                DateTime.Now, //Session Start Time
                DBNull.Value, //Session End Time
                true);

            //OnlineUsers Is A Table In MS SQL SERVER 2008  

            //InsertRow  Is A StoredProcedure Of OnlineUsers Table Like Below :  


//    ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_OnlineUsers_Insert]
//    @Session_ID nvarchar(300),
//    @Session_Start datetime,
//    @Session_End datetime = NULL,
//    @Online bit
//As
//Begin
//    Insert Into OnlineUsers
//        ([Session_ID],[Session_Start],[Session_End],[Online])
//    Values
//        (@Session_ID,@Session_Start,@Session_End,@Online)

//    Declare @ReferenceID int
//    Select @ReferenceID = @@IDENTITY

//    Return @ReferenceID

//End

            Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] + 1;
            Application.UnLock();
        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Lock();

            OnlineUsers.UpdateRow_Some_Fields_By_SessionID(
                Session.SessionID,
                DateTime.Now,
                false);

//UpdateRow_Some_Fields_By_SessionID Is A StoredProcedure Of OnlineUsers Table Like Below :  

//    ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_OnlineUsers_Update_Some_Fields_By_SessionID]
//    @Session_ID nvarchar(300),
//    @Session_End datetime,
//    @Online bit
//As
//Begin
//    Update OnlineUsers
//    Set
//        [Session_End] = @Session_End,
//        [Online] = @Online
//    Where     
//        [Session_ID] = @Session_ID

//End

            Application["OnlineUsers"] = (int)Application["OnlineUsers"] - 1;
            Application.UnLock();
        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

i have to labels in my project for showing OnlineUsers!

## 1 is using :

```
Application["OnlineUsers"].ToString();
```

## 2 is using :

```
OnlineUsers.Count_Users().ToString();

    //Count_Users Is A StoredProcedure Of OnlineUsers Like Below :  
    //ALTER Procedure [dbo].[sp_OnlineUsers_Count]
    //    As
    //    Begin
    //        Select 
    //            [Session_ID],
    //            [Session_Start],
    //            [Session_End],
    //            [Online]
    //        From OnlineUsers
    //        Where 
    //            [Online] = 1

    //        Declare @Count int
    //        Select @Count = @@ROWCOUNT

    //        Return @Count
    //    End
```

SomeTimes Lable 1 Shows Us : 5
but Lable 2 Shows Us : 255

what did i do wrong about them ?
why there is a big difference between them?

**EDIT**
my sessionState in web.config is like this :

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1" />
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Session_End` is only fired when the session times out, so that's why the counts don't match. Try using `Session.IsNewSession` to key off your `Session_End` logic instead.

Comment: really thanks for attention! plz see my edit and after that would you plz give me some explain about Session.IsNewSession!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your OnlineUsers table is holding a large number of users that never got cleaned up.

Session_End isn't a very reliable event and doesn't run 100% of the time. For instance, if the application stops unexpectedly, it won't run Session_End for each open Session. You would then have a listing of users stuck in OnlineUsers that would never get cleaned up. Application["OnlineUsers"] of course also wouldn't get cleaned up, but if your application was restarting, then it's be set back to 0, so you're not going to notice that big difference there.

Comment: Yup. Session_End is so flaky as to be nearly useless, IMHO.

Comment: thanks for answer, so what can we do about OnlineUsers In .net? what is the best way for showing them?

Comment: @MoonLight Honestly, I don't know. It's not a feature I would ever suggest for someone to add to a site personally. I would search around here and see if anything suits you: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net%5D+show+online+users